# What kind of simplified structural system would a Leonardo bridge use?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures, bridges

What kind of simplified structural system would a Leonardo bridge use?

I've tried approximating the system to a simple statically determined beam (see below) but our calculations did not give any realistic results. I believe it is due to a negligence of the potential strain in each beam. Maybe using a Spring Load Constant combined with nodes would help?
[image]
A [Leonardo bridge](http://www.leonardodavincisinventions.com/leonardo-da-vinci-models/leonardo-da-vincis-self-supporting-bridge/) is a bridge constructed without any kind of binding, but just using uniform length pieces of Wood. It can be constructed in this manner:
[image]

My own approximation is rough but each of the connections cannot be considered nodes because none of the pieces are loose or movable.
[image]

P.S. It would greatly simplify my calculations if any answers would consider a statically determined system even if it is a simplification.

Comment: It should only be referred to as a "Leonardo" bridge.  Signed, your local art historian.   For those who care: "da Vinci,"  as with (Rembrandt) van Rjin, indicates the birthplace of a person and is not actually a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will solve for n members with these assumptions.
members are L ft long by 2H, (H=L/20) thick and assuming the notch depth at H on the center to accommodate next member linkage.

Loads are applied uniformly spread vertically over the exposed top of the bridge at m. ton/ meter.
The structure as we add to members looks more and more like an arch.

The radius of which is deduced from similar triangles H/L = L/R
$R=L^2/h$

From here we apply as an approximation the arch formulas with one caveat the moment will be converted to compression and tension on the joints by this formula
$T=C=M/H$ and also shear converts to vertical joint loads.
There are many ways to solve a pin end support arch but an starter is to assume one support on rollers and solve then superimpose the lateral load needed to bring the roller end back in. I have some hand books if you need, but here is a link.
   http://www.civilengineeringx.com/bdac/stresses-in-arches/